# Picking value from a list to create another

Tags: python, list

I am trying to write a code that picks values in from a list to create to separate lists.

This is my code so far;

```
list = [6,2,9,10]
for x, y in zip(list, list):
      print (x,y)
```

Output:

```
6,2
9,10
```

But what I want is:

```
[6,9]
[2,10]
```

Comment: Do you want to separate elements located at odd and even indices into two different lists or what are you trying to accomplish? I'm not sure I understand it from your example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Have edit my code sorry. It could be either way but also want to sum them after but my case does not allow me to sum them.

Comment: `new_lst = [lst[i::2] for i in range(len(lst) // 2)]`

Comment: olvin Right your code worked perfectly

Comment: @Ranaz116m do not use `list` or other built-in function names as name of variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip slices of your original list to achieve your goal:

```
list = [6,2,9,10]
for x, y in zip(list[:2], list[2:]):
      print (x,y)
6 9
2 10
```

This is not well-generalized - if you had a specific intent like "split my list into a first-half and second-half, and match the elements of those sub-lists" that would be more clear, but hopefully this helps you achieve what you want.

Comment: And if it separating based on even and odd indices, simply `lst_of_even_indices = lst[::2]` and `lst_of_odd_indices = lst[1::2]` will work.

Comment: Nice one @shmulvad!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the elements at even index and odd index split into separate lists, you could do the following.

```py
List1 =[1, 2,3,4,5]
even_list= List1[::2]
Odd_list = List1[1::2]
```